# ExecuteStoreQuery and "WHERE IN ({0})

Tags: sql, executestorequery

I got the following code:

```
string query = "select * from dbo.Personnel where PersonnelId in ({0})";
string param = "1, 2";
var test = model.ExecuteStoreQuery<Personnel>(query, param).ToList();
```

I get the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1, 2' to data type int."...

Does anyone know how to solve this? What I want is `select * from dbo.Personnel where PersonnelId in (1, 2)` but the numbers can be any numbers...

Comment: I believe that because you don't escape the ',' char it's trying to convert the whole string - maybe try with "1\, 2".

Comment: What language is this? Also, it doesn't work because you're passing a *single* *string* parameter, and expecting SQL to somehow decide to split that into *multiple* *int* parameters - do you know of *any* language that has that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send param to `ExecuteStoreQuery`, just replace `{0}` with `param`

```
string param = "1, 2";
string query = string.Format("select * from dbo.Personnel where PersonnelId in ({0})", param);
```

or

```
string query = "select * from dbo.Personnel where PersonnelId in ({0})";
query = query.Replace("{0}",param);

var test = model.ExecuteStoreQuery<Personnel>(query).ToList();
```